# Total and partial derivatives

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The following piece of *Mathematica* code calculates the total derivative of a function $f(x,y(x))$ and compares it with what it should be. However, the result is not zero:

```
ff = f[x,y[x]];
Dt[ff,x] - (D[ff,x] + D[ff,y[x]] y'[x]) // FullSimplify
```

I can see that that

```
D[ff,x]
```

gives the total derivative as well and not $\partial f/\partial x$ while keeping $y(x)$ fixed. What am I missing here?

Comment: `D` is applying the chain rule. What else would you expect? If `y` were e.g. `Sqrt` or `Sin`, would you expect `D[f[x, Sin[x]], x] == f'[x, Sin[x]]`?

Comment: Maybe what you want is: `ff = f[x, y];
Dt[ff, x] - (D[ff, x] + D[ff, y] Dt[y, x])`

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this initially treats $x$ and $y$ as two independent variables (first command). This means that I cannot use `y'[x]` in the second command but, instead, the total differential `Dt[y,x]`.

Comment: Nikie, this helps a lot. `D[y,x]` is zero as it probably treats $y$ as a constant, whereas `D[y[x],x]` is the same as `y'[x]`. But when we use just `y`, one must take `Dt[y,x]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a close look at what is happening in your example. As you created two functions `f, ff` that both depend on only one real valued variable `x`, `Dt[ff,x]` and `D[ff,x]` have to be the same. Essentially the Jacobi matrix delivered by `Dt` consists only of $\frac{\partial ff}{\partial x}$.

To come back to your specific example you are making the mistake of using `D[ff,x]` when you only want the derivative of `f` with respect to its first component at the point `{x, y[x]}`. So what you really want is the following:

```
ff[x_, z_] := f[x, z]
Dt[ff[x, y[x]], x] - ((D[ff[x, z], x] /. z -> y[x]) + D[ff[x, y[x]], y[x]] y'[x]) // FullSimplify
```

Note that `(D[ff[x, z], x] /. z -> y[x])` is the derivative of `f` with respect to its first component evaluated at `{x, y[x]}`.

Comment: I see, this is a bit more complicated but works fine when I explicitly write `ff[x,y[x]]`.